# Javascript sending dynamic values to CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Jquery and im having trouble updating my CSS value on the fly during a hover event  . Basically i want that little line at the bottom to scale to the scale in length to the size of the div.

Here is the problematic code in question:

```
$('.menu li').hover(function () {
   left = Math.round($(this).offset().left - $('.menu').offset().left);
   //find the current width of the div
   var width_flux = $('.menu #box .head').html($(this).find('img').width());
   //pass value to CSS 
   $('.menu #box .head').css('width', (parseInt(width_flux)) +'px');
   $('#box').stop(false, true).animate({left: left},{duration:500, easing: style}); 

   //if user click on the menu
});
```

**and the corresponding css**

---

```
.menu #box .head {
        background: url("http://whoisedward.com/img/bar.png");
        height:3px;
        width:1px;
        color:#eee;

        /* force text display in one line */
        white-space:nowrap;

        /* set the text position manually */
        padding-left:4px;
        padding-top:3px;
    }
```

Comment: First off, you might want to change `hover` to `mouseenter` as right now the javascript is throwing errors on hover off because the hover binds to both hover on and off. http://api.jquery.com/hover/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: `var width_flux = $('.menu #box .head').find('img').width()` should fix that. Right now it's returning an object, instead of an explicit integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is problem in line

```
 var width_flux = $('.menu #box .head').html($(this).find('img').width());
```

`width_flux` is not with but `jQuery` element.

Modified code: Assuming you want use `$(this).find('img').width()` as `width_flux`

```
$('.menu li').hover(function () {
    left = Math.round($(this).offset().left - $('.menu').offset().left);
    //find the current width of the div
    var width_flux = $(this).find('img').width();
    //pass value to CSS 
    $('.menu #box .head').width(width_flux);
    $('#box').stop(false, true).animate({left: left},{duration:500, easing: style});    

    //if user click on the menu
})
```

Comment: I think maybe he wants: `$('.menu #box .head img').width();`

Comment: I see, so how do I change it to fetch the div size or simply find the  html width element on the page and store it in width_flux variable?

Comment: @Edward whose width you want use?

Answer (score 1):

The line

`var width_flux = $('.menu #box .head').html($(this).find('img').width());`

is wrong. You add the width to the element, but the element (not the width) is assigned to width_flux. Obviously, `<element>px` is not a sensible CSS value.

Try:

```
width_flux = $(this).find('img').width();
$('.menu #box .head').html(width_flux);
$('.menu #box .head').css('width', width_flux + 'px');
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be setting the value to you HTML and not getting it

```
var width_flux = $('.menu #box .head').html($(this).find('img').width());
```

So basically width_flux will be an element..

Instead try

```
var width_flux = $(this).find('img').width();

   OR 

var width_flux = $('.menu #box .head').html($(this).find('img').width());

   var width_flux = width_flux.html() ;
    // Then your code
```

Make sure you check for error conditions